# Zend Framework (Twitter Search) JSON problem since_id

Tags: php, zend-framework, search, twitter

I'm using `Zend_Service_Twitter` to run a Twitter search and return json. I'm having a problem with the `since_id` values I'm getting back. When I `print_r()` the search results, I get back the following:

```
...
[since_id] => -2017847207  
[refresh_url] => ?since_id=6801825835&q=myTwitterSearchQuery
...
```

The `[since_id]` value is different to the querystring `since_id` - this means that the next search I run using the stored since_id doesn't  return anything.

Anyone have suggestions on what might be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: The integer has gone up and over perhaps? Maybe it is time for BigInt... or you could pull it from the refresh_url and store it as a string.

Comment: I don't think this really has anything to do with the zend-framework btw...

Comment: Yes, I reckoned the next step was to pull it out of the refresh_url, but I was curious as to why it was happening in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [logged bug](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7122) in Zend_Service_Twitter.  That bug report lists the spots where you'd want to not cast to int.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely related to [The Twitpocalypse](http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/06/12/all-hell-may-break-loose-on-twitter-in-2-hours/) that happened back in June.  Although I'm suprised Zend hasn't taken care of this.  But basically Twitter's id has gone over the max for signed integers and you are overflowing.  You should switch to storing this some other way.  Since php may make this difficult that you might just want to store them as strings.